# Can't save parent-child with one-to-one relationship

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Imagine, you have next entities:

```
@Entity(name = "software")
@Table(name = "software")
public class SoftwareEntity {

   @Id
   UUID id;
   String name;
   String description;
   // other properties
 
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "current_version",
                    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "sowtware_id")},
                    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "version_id")})

   VersionEntity currentVersion;
}

@Entity(name = "version")
@Table(name = "version")
public class VersionEntity {

   @Id
   @Column("version_id")
   UUID versionId;

   @Column("software_id")
   UUID softwareId;

   // other properties
}
```

In Version entity, I don't like to hold the whole parent SoftwareEntity. I only need the identifier.

In database level I have next tables:

```
CREATE TABLE software {
  id       UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  name                    STRING,
  description             STRING
}

CREATE TABLE version {
   version_id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
   software_id UUID NOTNULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (software_id) REFERENCES software (id)
}

CREATE TABLE current_version {
     software_id       UUID NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     version_id        UUID NOT NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY (software_id, version_id),

     FOREIGN KEY (software_id) REFERENCES software (id),
     FOREIGN KEY (version_id) REFERENCES version (version_id)
}
```

My typical use case is the following:

```
var software = createNewSoftware();
var version = createNewVersion(software.id());
software.setCurrentVersion(version);
...
softwareJpaRepository.save(software); // fails here
```

When I do so, JPA is going to save version first but fails because new software entity is not saved yet and there is foreign key constraint in version table.
(org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException)

If I disable cascade option in one-to-one relationship between software and version, JPA is seeking saving version first and also fails because such version is not yet saved. (javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException)

Does anybody know how to fix it keeping the same/similar structure of entities and tables?

Comment: Why do you need join table for one to one relationship? Because I generally do that for many to many

Comment: Okay. Since, it is one to one relationship, I though a separate table was not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set the ***software entity id*** and ***version entity id*** directly on the code itself:

```
@Id
private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
```

And, you can save the software entity in this manner:

```
// Software entity id already set
SoftwareEntity softwareEntity = new SoftwareEntity();
       
//version entity id already set
VersionEntity versionEntity = new VersionEntity();
//foreign key set
versionEntity.setSoftwareId(softwareEntity.getId());

softwareEntity.setCurrentVersion(versionEntity);
softwareEntityRepository.save(softwareEntity);
```

Comment: Not sure how it helps. I do the same via factory methods.

Comment: When trying to save the version, this time the foreign key constraint won't fail because software entity id is already being set. If you also had done the same, then I wonder why the exception is occurring. It is working for me.